# change directory based on file shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, tar, cd-command

Firstly come background I am trying to write an executable shell script I can easily map as the default for .tgz files to auto-extract.

so far so simple

```
tar -xzvf $1
```

which works to drag/drop but not if I double click. Since I can use it if files are in the same location I assume it is because of the current working directory of the script.

However equally shouldn't $1 pass the full file path to the tar command so it doesn't matter?

Anyway I then thought the answer would be the pwd command then the dirname command i.e.

```
cd 'dirname $1'
```

but that didn't work
A google around suggested

```
cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$1")" && pwd -P
```

But I still can't get this script to work. It may not be the right error.

Comment: You should add information on why/how the cd command fails.

Answer (score 0):

No, `$1` does NOT expand to the full file path, it actually is the exact first argument - also if the file is non-existent.

A simple `echo $1` does reveal this.

Instead of a clumsy directory change, just make use of the `-C` flag.

> `man tar`
>
> -C, --directory=DIR
>
> Change to DIR before performing any operations.  This option is order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.

I.e. your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -C "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$1")")" -xzvf "$1"
```

Comment: thanks mate. It must be another issue. Still only works on drag/drop but if set as the default handler. It outputs

Cannot open file no such file or directory.

Comment: Is your script in the PATH? How did you specify the handler?

Comment: Is not in path. Was specified through open via custom command using the standard pcmanfm file properties panel

Comment: Did you use quotes? e.g. `"$1"`? How about using the full path `-xzvf "$(readlink -f "$1")"`? Anything noticeable when you run it from the shell via `bash -x script.sh test.tar.gz`?

Comment: No change on using the quoted command. running using bash -x it works as it did before and uses the current working directory not switching.

Comment: How about the `--one-top-level="$(basename "$(readlink "$1")")"` option? Could you add details about your DE and how you defined the "default option"?

Comment: Video showing default setting here.
https://myntuac-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/daniel_kendall_su_ntu_ac_uk/EcLTVO--oHhAveUGEi8UwrMBqLrO3rMyqJpTX2MepptQSQ

Comment: `tar -xzvf --one-top-level="$(basename "$(readlink "$1")")" "$(readlink -f "$1")"`.

Comment: tar (child): --one-top-level=: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Comment: Error from my side: `--one-top-level="$(dirname "$(readlink "$1")")"`

Comment: Sadly no change